# Crash when animation flare animation is display after flutter upgrade only with IOS device

Tags: flutter, flare

After made a big migration of flutter, I have crash when animation is display, I had no crash before. It only crash on ios iphone 11 device.

it seems to crash only with animation who have some key animation

I can't change the animation file, how can I prevent this crash ?

I use  `flare_flutter: ^3.0.2`

here is my flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.4, on macOS 13.5 22G74 darwin-arm64, locale fr-FR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

here is the log during the crash

```
* thread #10, name = 'io.flutter.1.raster', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x000000010d8a8b78 Flutter`tessTesselate + 2436
Flutter`tessTesselate:
->  0x10d8a8b78 <+2436>: ldr    x3, [x1]
    0x10d8a8b7c <+2440>: ldr    s1, [x3, #0x24]
    0x10d8a8b80 <+2444>: fcmp   s1, s0
    0x10d8a8b84 <+2448>: mov    x4, x1
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
Lost connection to device.
```